# Is there a way to mock python library method on development environment?

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, python-decorators

I'm building an app in python 3.8 that uses third-party libraries (e.g. google-calendar, AWS-compute, etc. ).
In my **development environment**, I want to mock the method's response from these third-party libraries instead of calling the actual services.
The same way it's done with @patch decorator in the test environments.

Is there any way to inject the returned value in the development environment?